# WPF in VB Text Box 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: wpf, vb.net

so here is simple WPF application I made to practice OO concepts. It has the user input a number in feet and converts to meters by outputting a message box.

```
Class MainWindow

Dim lengthInMeters = txtBox1.Text '***An exception of type "System.NullReferenceException" occurred***

Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    MessageBox.Show(COptions.GetLength(lengthInMeters), "Conversion Successful!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
End Sub
End Class
```

And my other Class file:

```
Public Class COptions
Public Shared Function GetLength(lengthInMeters) As Double
    Return lengthInMeters / 3.28
End Function
End Class
```

Also, here is the XAML for the textbox:

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="txtBox1" 
    x:FieldModifier="public" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="23" 
    Margin="200,140,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120" 
    enderTransformOrigin="1.29,-3.252" 
    Grid.Column="1"
    />
```

I am getting a NullReference at "Dim lengthInMeters = txtBox1.Text" and I believe I need to instantiate my object reference? But how?

- Thank you for your help!

Comment: `txtBox1` is null. Is that code totally garbled, or are you really trying to initialize a field there?

Comment: When do you really want to convert `txtBox1.Text` to a number?

Comment: If this is WPF you should bind your control to a property.

Comment: @EdPlunkett when the user clicks the button.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Just had to move it into the subroutine button_Click. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields are initialized before the constructor runs, and GUI components initialized in the constructor, so `txtBox1` has not been initialized at the point you are using it, as you have found out.  Even if it did work, it would capture the value of the text box at that point, which is before the user has had a chance to enter anything.

Instead, move the `Dim lengthInMeters = txtBox1.Text` line into your button click handler, so that you get the current value of the text box just before you use it.  Your current code is also relying on some implicit type conversions - I would recommend turning `Option Strict On` to catch these, and use explicit conversions.

```
Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    Dim lengthInMeters = CDbl(txtBox1.Text)
    MessageBox.Show(COptions.GetLength(lengthInMeters), "Conversion Successful!", MessageBoxButton.OK)
End Sub

Public Class COptions
    Public Shared Function GetLength(lengthInMeters As Double) As Double
        Return lengthInMeters / 3.28
    End Function
End Class
```